# Not able to start the ATG server

Tags: java, server, atg

I am getting this error while server restart.Please help me out.This is first time I am getting this error. I dont find any compile time errors also.

```
Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.error.error500_jsp
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:135)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:67)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatInjectionContainer.newInstance(TomcatInjectionContainer.java:249)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:145)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:324)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at com.autozone.diy.servlet.filter.JSessionRemoveFilter.doFilter(JSessionRemoveFilter.java:80)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at atg.filter.dspjsp.PageFilter.innerDoFilter(PageFilter.java:234)
        at atg.filter.dspjsp.PageFilter.doFilter(PageFilter.java:208)
        at atg.filter.dspjsp.AZPageFilter.doFilter(AZPageFilter.java:35)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at atg.filter.dspjsp.PageFilter.innerDoFilter(PageFilter.java:234)
        at atg.filter.dspjsp.PageFilter.doFilter(PageFilter.java:208)
        at atg.filter.dspjsp.AZPageFilter.doFilter(AZPageFilter.java:35)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:183)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:95)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:451)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Thanks in advance. Please help me out with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the giver jsp is not found by the Server.
Check whether you have given correct jsp path or not.